# TSQL / .net transaction handling LinqToClasses DataClassesDataContext

Tags: .net, t-sql, linq-to-sql, transactions

I am using T/SQL stored procedures to ensure that if data gets into the database the data has integrity. I use boilerplate code for the stored procedures to wrap up the stored procedure in a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp<SprocName,,> 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @tranIsLocal bit, @errNo int

IF @@TRANCOUNT =0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tr_sp<SprocName,,> 
    SET @tranIsLocal = 1
END

/* Do Stuff Here 

 update table1
      ...

 if @@Error<>0
 Begin
      set @errNo=1
      goto ErrorHandler
 end


select Results ...
 if @@Error<>0
 Begin
      set @errNo=1
      goto ErrorHandler
 end

if @tranIsLocal <>0
begin
    COMMIT TRANSACTION   tr_sp<SprocName,,> 
end 
return 0
ErrorHandler:
if @tranIsLocal <>0
begin 
        rollback transaction  tr_sp<SprocName,,> 
end
    return @errNo
END
GO
```

I know this would probably be better done with Try Catch but unless it actually helps the issue in hand I do not wish to address this.

In particular I need to update two tables I want to be certain that it is not possible for one table to be updated but not the other.

I am using LinqToClasses because the code I have inherited (from my predecessor) does it this way and it is undoubtedly faster to have the classes ready coded rather than hand coding the data layer interface.

I assume that ExecuteMethodCall wraps the call to the database up in a transaction itself.

So since the stored procedure checks to see if there are any transactions before creating a transaction and tests whether the transaction was created by the stored procedure before calling roll back transaction.

The question is what if anything do I have to do to ensure that the transaction will be rolled back on failure by .net.

Will ExecuteMethodCall check the return value and roll back the transaction?

If not can I check the return value as well bringing back a results set from the DataClassesDataContext?

Can I make the ExecuteMethodCall roll back the transaction by calling RAISEERROR or THROW in the stored procedure?

Ideally is there any documentation that clarifies how Microsoft handle transactions on the .net side of things with respect to ExecuteMethodCall?